# reorganising data frame in R

Tags: r, reshape2

I have a data frame that two main group ID, i.e. Sample Number (num) and time series (group) with its associated two variables Hyper and Hypo. I am trying to change them to have them grouped by both sample number and time series. I tried acast to do so but ended up getting "NA" values.

```
 > myres
          group              Hyper           Hypo     num
    69    C13D1                9              15 503-a
    51    C05D1               10              14 503-b
    61    C07D1               14              10 503-b
    46    C05D1               13              11 504-c
    55    C07D1               12              13 504-c
    64    C09D1               15               9 504-c
    78      SCR               13              11 504-c
    31    C02D1               15               9 504-d
    52    C05D1               14              10 504-d
    67    C09D1                9              15 504-d
    24    C02D1               17               7 504-e
    40    C03D1               16               8 504-e
    53    C05D1               10              14 504-e
    75      EOT               17               7 504-e
    92      SCR               14              10 504-e
```

The way I went about trying to change is as follows.

```
acast(myres, formula=group ~ num ~ Hyper)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `acast(DF, group ~ num, value.var="Hyper")` works fine. For both vars, maybe you want `acast(melt(DF, id=c("group", "num")), group ~ num ~ variable)`

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is what you wanted but if you're using the `tidyr` package you can do `spread(myres, num, hyper)`

Comment: acast(melt(DF, id=c("group", "num")), group ~ num ~ variable). This is most useful. Thanks